# How to set up Keyboard Maestro correctly so that it doesn't catch its own Macro?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I used to insert <kbd>;</kbd> character by pressing button below <kbd>ESC</kbd> on Windows, (which does <kbd><</kbd> on MacBook) and <kbd>$</kbd> by holding <kbd>alt</kbd> + the button next to <kbd>L</kbd> key on Windows.

I've downloaded Keyboard Maestro and it worked pretty well on Yosemite, but on El Capitan, it somehow, probably, does catch its own keystrokes, randomly. I've got two Macros:

- <kbd>⌥;</kbd> - should write $
- <kbd><</kbd> (below esc) - should write ;

The problem is, that when I press <kbd><</kbd>, it does catch my Macro, wants to insert correct keystroke (<kbd>;</kbd>) but somehow inserts <kbd>$</kbd> for unknown reason (maybe because when they simulate original shortcut for <kbd>;</kbd>, which is <kbd>⌥;</kbd>, second Macro catches it?). It does happen very randomly. Quick try:

```
;$;$$$$$$$$$$$$;$$$$$;$$$$$$$;$$;$;$
```

How should I workaround this without having to add any more keys or something like that?